# excel, VBA, duplicate values

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I have a large spreadsheet I was asked to edit. Basically wherever the data was pulled from, it created several duplicates of individuals names, country, start dates, and end dates. Would it be possible to get the start and stop dates in adjacent cells and remove the duplicate data?

I have provided a screen shot. Manually copying, pasting, and deleting would take a very long time since this spreadsheet has over 2300 rows with approximately 50% being duplicates that will need edited.

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1):

VBA shouldn't be necessary here, just add a new column with the formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(C1,D1)
```

Replace the column letters with your column letters for Start Date and End Date.

You can then use Excel's remove duplicates function on the new column (Data -> Remove Duplicates)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL is suitable.

```
Sub myQuery()
    Dim strSQL  As String
    Dim strTable As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    strTable = "[" & ActiveSheet.Name & "$]"

    strSQL = "SELECT NAME, COUNTRY, MIN([Start Date]) as [Start Date] , max([End Date]) as [End Date] "
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM " & strTable & " "
    strSQL = strSQL & " Where not isnull(NAME) "
    strSQL = strSQL & " Group by NAME, COUNTRY "

    Set Ws = Sheets.Add

    exeSQL strSQL, Ws

End Sub

Sub exeSQL(strSQL As String, Ws As Worksheet)

    Dim Rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"


    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Rs.Open strSQL, strConn

    If Not Rs.EOF Then
         With Ws
            .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
            For i = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
               .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = Rs.Fields(i).Name
            Next
            .Range("a" & 2).CopyFromRecordset Rs
            .Columns.AutoFit
        End With
    End If
    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have access to SQL Server Management Studio unfortunately. Is there another way to run this without SQL?